# JS tooltip issues: tool tip remains after button is clicked

Tags: javascript

**osvaldas.info/elegant-css-and-jquery-tooltip-responsive-mobile-friendly** Does anyone have experience with this tool tip ? seems to work really well - but the way i have it set up, the tool tip 'lingers' after a form button (image) is clicked A script is called to a small section of the page and users make a selection. The tool tip explains the selection options.

The page is not refreshed - data is sent to a db and a 'confirmation' is displayed.

Problem is the tool tip lingers but would like it to clear after the users clicks

Comment: if you include code you are using it will be easier for people to help

Comment: noted - will do that next time .... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the Javascript code of Tooltip given on the website you mentioned.
I think the area of problem is this code in the bottom of tooltip Javascript

```
target.bind( 'mouseleave', remove_tooltip );
```

As of jQuery 3.0, bind is deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/bind/.
You might want to use `.on()` method there instead. Something like

```
target.on( 'mouseleave', remove_tooltip );
```

Please also note that the tooltip Javascript doesn't consider target click as the trigger to remove tooltip. So you should also add this line in the bottom of tooltip javascript

```
target.on( 'click', remove_tooltip );
```

Comment: That seems to have cured the issue - thank you very much

Comment: If my answer solved your query, can you mark it as "answer"?